# Given $f(x,y) = x$ if $y \neq x^2$, $f(x,y) = 0$ if $y = x^2$ how to show it is not differentiable at (0,0) though all directional derivatives exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

While reading a Wikipedia entry on Differentiable Functions, specifically [Differentiability in higher dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), I saw the following:

> However, the existence of the partial derivatives (or even of all the directional derivatives) does not in general guarantee that a function is differentiable at a point. For example, the function f: R2 → R defined by $$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
>         x & \text{if } y \neq x^2 \\
>         0 & \text{if } y = x^2 \\
>         \end{array}\right.$$
> is not differentiable at (0, 0), but all of the partial derivatives and directional derivatives exist at this point.

All directional derivatives exist at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, and it is continuous, but how do we know that $f$ is not differentiable at this point?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question is about the same function: [Partial derivatives exist and derivative does not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1692893)